# Randomly Get Erro 500, from IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, iis, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I have a stranger problem I have an ASP web API that published on IIS 10 (Win2019), and the API connected with Oracle Database on another Server. the project is working fine but some requests were failer with an error 500, this issue happens randomly, and some times the WebSite on the IIS goes freezing and need a restart to works again.

I enable the trace error tracking from IIS and I get this warning :

---

ModuleName
ManagedPipelineHandler

Notification
EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER

HttpStatus
500

HttpReason
Internal Server Error

HttpSubStatus
0

ErrorCode
The operation completed successfully.
(0x0)

ConfigExceptionInfo

---

, this website published with require a Client SSL Certificate, I found some people talking about this maybe happed when enable the client certificate required like this https://boyan.io/random-500-errors-iis-client-certificates/

but this not resolve the issue, and also try to disable the Client SSL required, and the same issue still.

Any idea to troubleshoot this error,

Thanks

Comment: Error 500 means there was an error in the program (asp.net) and IIS won't reveal the error. It will log the error in the NT Event Logs under System or Application. It is better if you are using an error logger like ELMAH to record the errors. Do you have an error logger?  Check the NT Event logs and tell us what you find.

Answer (score 0):

What do you set the managed pipeline mode of the application pool to, and what is the identity of the application pool?

In most cases, this problem occurs because the application pool is set to classic mode, and changing to integrated mode can solve it.

According to another possibility described in the document, damage to the .net framework can also cause this problem. Use the command to fix it.

- If the computer is running the full Microsoft .NET Framework, enter the following commands to change to the Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SetupCache folder, and then run setup.exe:

  ```
  cd\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SetupCache
  setup.exe /repair /x86 /x64 /ia64 /norestart
  ```
- If the computer is running the Microsoft .NET Framework client profile, enter the following commands to change to the Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Client folder, and then run the setup.exe:

  ```
  cd\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Client
  setup.exe /repair /x86 /x64 /ia64 /parameterfolder Client /norestart
  ```

At last.

```
iisreset
```

Comment: Thank You for the replay, the application pool working in integrated mode, and try your solution but the problem still accrued.